# Python background color of main frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my main frame to have the background color black. Here is what I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("363x200")
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Emsg Server")
root.option_add("*background", "black")

v = StringVar()

Field = Message(root, textvariable=v, width=330, fg="blue")
Field.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

My attempt above with `root.option_add("*background", "black")`, just creates one single small black box located north west.

How do you make the entire application black?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to use

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

instead of

```
root.option_add("*background", "black")
```

As an extra: you don't need two import statements, the second one is enough.

Comment: Thanks man, and thanks for the add up. I've always wondered why both of them would be needed :)

Comment: It says I need at least 15 rep for it.

Comment: But if Tk(bg="black") does not work, but Tk().config(bg="black") does, why?

Comment: @KnasScripter: the answer to why `Tk(bg="black")` doesn't work is simply because it's a bug (or the result of a design decision). The reason the `config` method works is because it was designed to work.

Comment: Personally, I think `import Tkinter as tk; root=tk.Tk()...` is the better way to go. Doing an `import *` for any module is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Wouldn't I need to preceed every widget with tk then?

Answer (score 3):

`option_add` merely adds an entry to the option database, it doesn't affect any existing options. It merely defined defaults used when widgets are created. Since the root window is created before you update the database, that window will not inherit that option property.

To change the color of the main widget (or any widget once it's been created), use the `configure` method. This method lets you change almost any configuration option for a widget.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
root["bg"]="black"
```

Answer (score -1):

in this case you should do the following

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

instead of

```
root.option_add("*background", "black")
```

Comment: why did you add an answer that is almost an exact duplicate of the existing, accepted answer?